# how to concatenate names in a DF whit with surnames when there are nan entries

Tags: python, pandas

well i have this DF in python

```
           folio  id_incidente            nombre         app        apm  \
0              1             1         SIN DATOS   SIN DATOS  SIN DATOS   
1            131        100085      JUAN DOMINGO    GONZALEZ    DELGADO   
2            132        100085  FRANCISCO JAVIER        VELA    RAMIREZ   
3            133        100087       JUAN CARLOS       PEREZ     MEDINA   
4            134        100088           ARMANDO     SALINAS    SALINAS   
...          ...           ...               ...         ...        ...   
1169697  1223258        866846             IVAN       RIVERA      SILVA   
1169698  1223259        866847           EDUARDO  PLASCENCIA   MARTINEZ   
1169699  1223260        866848  FRANCISCO JAVIER  PLASCENCIA   MARTINEZ   
1169700  1223261        866849      JUAN ALBERTO    MARTINEZ   ARELLANO   
1169701  1223262        866850     JOSE DE JESUS     SERRANO   GONZALEZ   

                       foto_barandilla  fecha_hora_registro  
0                                1.jpg    0/0/0000 00:00:00  
1                              131.jpg  2008-08-07 15:42:25  
2                              132.jpg  2008-08-07 15:50:42  
3                              133.jpg  2008-08-07 16:37:24  
4                              134.jpg  2008-08-07 17:18:12  
...                                ...                  ...  
1169697   20200330103123_239288573.jpg  2020-03-30 10:32:10  
1169698  20200330103726_1160992585.jpg  2020-03-30 10:38:25  
1169699   20200330103837_999151106.jpg  2020-03-30 10:39:44  
1169700    20200330104038_29275767.jpg  2020-03-30 10:41:52  
1169701   20200330104145_640780023.jpg  2020-03-30 10:45:35
```

here the app and apm are the mother and father surnames, then i tried these in order to get another column with the whole name

```
names = {}
for i in range(1,df.shape[0]+1):
    try:
        names[i] = df["nombre"].iloc[i]+' '+df["app"].iloc[i]+' '+df["apm"].iloc[i]
    except:
        print(df["folio"].iloc[i], df["nombre"].iloc[i],df["app"].iloc[i],df["apm"].iloc[i])
```

but i get these

```
400085 nan nan nan
400631 nan nan nan
401267 nan nan nan
401933 nan nan nan
401942 nan nan nan
402030 nan nan nan
403008 nan nan nan
403010 nan nan nan
403011 nan nan nan
403027 nan nan nan
403384 nan nan nan
403399 nan nan nan
403415 nan nan nan
403430 nan nan nan
404764 nan nan nan
501483 CARLOS ESPINOZA nan
504723 RICARDO JARED LOPEZ ACOSTA nan
506989 JUAN JOSE FLORES OCHOA nan
507376 JOSE DE JESUS VENEGAS nan
.....
```

i tried to use the fillna.('') like this

```
df["app"].fillna('')
df["apm"].fillna('')
df["nombre"].fillna('')
```

but the result is the same, i hope you can help me in order to make the column with the whole name, like name+surname1+surname2

edit: here is my minimal version, the reporte files are(each one) a part of the whole database as show up here,

```
for i in range(1,31):
    exec('reporte_%d = pd.read_excel("/home/workstation/Desktop/fotos/Fotos/Detenidos/Reporte Detenidos CER %d.xlsx", encoding="latin1" )'%(i,i))   
reportes = [reporte_1,reporte_2,reporte_3,reporte_4,reporte_5,reporte_6,reporte_7,reporte_8,reporte_9,reporte_10,reporte_11,reporte_12,reporte_13,reporte_14,reporte_15,reporte_16,reporte_17,reporte_18,reporte_19,reporte_20,reporte_21,reporte_22,reporte_23,reporte_24,reporte_25,reporte_26,reporte_27,reporte_28,reporte_29,reporte_30]

df = pd.concat(reportes)
```

now when i run

```
df['Full_name'] = [' '.join([y for y in x if pd.notna(y)])  for x in zip(df['nombre'], df['app'], df['apm'])]
```

i get this error TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

Comment: `df['app'] = df["app"].fillna('')` You need to assign the result back. However you're going to run into issues with multiple and or trailing/leading whitespace. Give me a minute

Comment: I don't understand "foto_barandilla" on down. It looks like a different dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will `' '.join` all the words after removing the null values. It's a string operation and `apply(axis=1)` gets slow so we can use a list comprehension:

#### Sample Data

```
  nombre   app   apm
0    Mr.  blah   bar
1   blah  blah   foo
2    NaN   NaN   NaN
3   blah   Mr.   bar
4   blah   foo   Mr.
5    foo   Mr.  blah
6    NaN   Mr.   foo
7   blah   Mr.   NaN
8    NaN   bar   bar
9    foo   Mr.   Mr.
```

#### Code

```
df['Full_name'] = [' '.join([y for y in x if pd.notna(y)]) 
                   for x in zip(df['nombre'], df['app'], df['apm'])]

#  nombre   app   apm      Full_name
#0    Mr.  blah   bar   Mr. blah bar
#1   blah  blah   foo  blah blah foo
#2    NaN   NaN   NaN                  # value is the empty string `''`
#3   blah   Mr.   bar   blah Mr. bar
#4   blah   foo   Mr.   blah foo Mr.
#5    foo   Mr.  blah   foo Mr. blah
#6    NaN   Mr.   foo        Mr. foo
#7   blah   Mr.   NaN       blah Mr.
#8    NaN   bar   bar        bar bar
#9    foo   Mr.   Mr.    foo Mr. Mr.
```

Comment: hey man! i do as you said but i get this error sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

what could it be?

Comment: @mimus some of the values are numbers then. You can `.astype` the column to string, but that will mess with `NaN` values. I suggest you create a [mcve] that reproduces your problem and the errors you're seeing otherwise it's going to take forever to solve

Comment: done brother i hope you can give me some light here

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep your processing within `pandas` as much as possible. By building a python dictionary with strings, you explode your memory footprint and defeat the purpose of using pandas in the first place. You can use the pandas `str.concat` method to put the strings together, so nominally its just

```
df["Concatenated"] = df["nombre"].str.cat([df["app"], df["apm"]], sep=" ")
```

But it sounds like your dataframe need a bit of cleanup first. Like for instance, what is that "foto_barandilla  fecha_hora_registro" stuff half way down? Here is a fully worked example of a clean dataframe and concatenation

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = """folio  id_incidente            nombre         app        apm
      1             1         SIN DATOS   SIN DATOS  SIN DATOS   
    131        100085      JUAN DOMINGO    GONZALEZ    DELGADO   
    132        100085  FRANCISCO JAVIER        VELA    RAMIREZ   
    133        100087       JUAN CARLOS       PEREZ     MEDINA   
    134        100088           ARMANDO     SALINAS    SALINAS   
1223258        866846             IVAN       RIVERA      SILVA   
1223259        866847           EDUARDO  PLASCENCIA   MARTINEZ   
1223260        866848  FRANCISCO JAVIER  PLASCENCIA   MARTINEZ   
1223261        866849      JUAN ALBERTO    MARTINEZ   ARELLANO   
1223262        866850     JOSE DE JESUS     SERRANO   GONZALEZ"""

# make test dataframe

table = []
for line in data.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()
    table.append(re.split(r"\s{2,}", line))

df = pd.DataFrame(table[1:], columns=table[0])

# enusre data types and scrub the data
df = df.astype(
        {"folio":int, "id_incidente":int, "nombre":"string",
        "app":"string", "apm":"string"},errors="ignore")
df.update(df[["nombre", "app", "apm"]].fillna(" "))

# build new column
df["Concatenated"] = df["nombre"].str.cat([df["app"], df["apm"]], sep=" ")
print(df)

# ... or, if you don't want to scrub the dataframe first
df["Concatenated"] = df["nombre"].fillna(" ").str.cat(
    [df["app"].fillna(" "), df["apm"].fillna(" ")], sep=" ")
print("================================================")
print(df)
```